# Merge/combine two monitors into one desktop

Tags: gnu-screen, merge

I'm running Arch Linux on a PC with a ATI HD 5870, using the open source driver.

I have two HD-monitors and I want to "merge" these screens into one large desktop (3840x1080), so I can run a fullscreen application/game on both monitors.

I think "Xinerama" could do this, but it seems deprecated.

Comment: Arch Linux has a really good documentation wiki - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead

Comment: I know the wiki, but there is no solution to my problem.

Comment: My multihead setup works fine. I want to merge both screens, so that they work as one lage screen.
Something like AMD Eyefinity or NVIDIA mosaic / surround.

Comment: In other words, you want to spread one screen over two monitors. The Arch wiki covers several ways to do that. (merge and spread are kind of the same concept here). If you can't work with xrandr, use the xorg.conf method.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do this with xrandr? Where can I it in the Arch wiki?